# Extract Text from Website without any HTML tags with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]

Not able to extract the highlighted text alone as a string with selenium since those two are hardcoded texts without tags, kindly let me know any possiblilities.

Comment: Can you share that HTML in text format here? Stpes `Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> then right click on the element you want to share the outer HTML - > select copy and then outer HTML`

Comment: Please find the below :
user@phptravels.com 

The outer xml itself is a text. 

The url is <https://phptravels.com/demo/>

Its an automation practice website, you can have have a look

Comment: do you want to retrieve just `demouser` or `user@phptravels.com` along with `demouser` ?

Comment: I want both user@phptravels.com and demouser in different String variables so I can use them on the next url as inputs for id and password

Comment: okay for storing into different string variable I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below xpath:

```
//strong[text()='Customer']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::div[starts-with(@class,'col-md-10')]
```

like this:

```
String gottenText = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//strong[text()='Customer']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::div[@class='col-md-10']"))).getAttribute("innerText");
System.out.println(gottenText);
```

that shall provide the below output:

```
Email user@phptravels.com
Password demouser
```

**Update:**

you can store them into String variable like below:

```
String gottenText = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//strong[text()='Customer']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::div[@class='col-md-10']"))).getAttribute("innerText");
String[] arr = gottenText.split(" ");
String[] userNames = arr[1].split("\\r?\\n");
String userName = userNames[0];
String password = arr[2];
    
System.out.println(userName + " " + password);
```

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help, will try this out and update.

Comment: Thanks for your help man, much appreciated :)

Comment: Glad we could solve this together, cheers !